# grepl() in R producing odd results

Tags: r, grepl

I am trying to identify rows for which the value of one column contains the character string from another column. I *know* that many (hundreds) of rows meet this criteria. Yet when I use grepl() to identify those rows, I get a result indicating that no such matches exist.

`matches <- grepl(wtf$loc, wtf$Match_addr)`

`matching_rows <- wtf[matches, ]`

The output here is an empty table.

Weirder still, doing this:

`grepl(wtf$loc[5], wtf$Match_addr[5])`

`grepl(wtf$loc[4], wtf$Match_addr[4])`

`grepl(wtf$loc[6], wtf$Match_addr[6])`

`which(grepl(wtf$loc, wtf$Match_addr))`

generates this output:

`[1] TRUE`

`[1] TRUE`

`[1] TRUE`

`integer(0)`

If I index certain rows it seems to recognize the pattern match, but if I use grepl() and pass the entire columns as arguments there are no matches. How can this be possible?

Comment: Is `wtf$loc` a vector of length greater than 1? Did you by any chance see any warnings when you run this code?

Comment: Hello joran, thanks for responding. `wtf$loc` is vector of length 1,933. No warnings.

Comment: What version of R are you using? `grepl` is not vectorized over the pattern argument. When I run `grepl(c("a","b","c"), c("c","b","a"))` in R 4.2 I get a warning and in R 4.3 you should get an error.

Comment: I am using R 4.3.  Thanks for this. I am working in an .rmd in which the knitr::opts_chunk$set( warning = FALSE). When I set it to true for this chunk it produced the warning. Is there a way to achieve what I was going for with my misapplication of grepl()?

Comment: If you want to search for any of the strings in `loc` in a second vector, then one thing you could do is collapse the strings in `loc` into a single regex, separated by `|`. (That would be a long regex; not sure what the character limits are but I think you'd be ok.)

Comment: I suppose I will try an apply function to iterate over the whole vector.

Comment: Thanks joran, but if I understand you right that will not do. I need to know whether, for each row, the character string from `loc` is present in vector `Match_addr`. Not whether any string in `loc` appears in any other row in `Match_addr`. I hope that makes sense.